# AutoIt code to enable and disable windows taskbar

Tags: autoit

I am looking for a method to disable and enable the Windows taskbar and Start button using an AutoIt script.

Is it possible?

Comment: This is not a code writing website. What have you tried? We can help you from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
Opt('WINTITLEMATCHMODE', 4)
ControlHide('classname=Shell_TrayWnd', '', '')
Sleep(3000)
ControlShow('classname=Shell_TrayWnd', '', '')
```